# AngularJS store product details with ngStorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

How should we store the Product ID, Product Name,Product Size and Product Price using ngStorage or Local Storage, when the customer adds the product to the cart and disply all the products in the cart page? It seems like multi-dimensional arrays aren't that effective with ngStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a cartService/factory with getters and setters.  Since all services in angular are singletons the information will be stored for the lifetime of the app.

This way you can store any data that you would like.

Comment: but the information will be gone if you reload the page

Comment: and i really need to keep them stored..else i could have used an array...but data would go, once refreshed!

Comment: You would need a backend connected to some sort of database.  This will be the only way to store information in an app.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at pouchdb.js, its nosql. Just store the data as an object and persist it using pouchdb. it creates a level of abstraction that takes care of a lot. You don't have to worry if the browser supports localstorage or indexdb, it will handle that for you.

You can store the data and the client and it will persist even when refreshed.